# Wire up MiniProfiler to ASP.NET Core Web API Swagger

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger-ui, asp.net-core-webapi, mvc-mini-profiler

I found only [this manual](http://www.lambdatwist.com/webapi-profiling-with-miniprofiler-swagger/) describing how to make MiniProfiler work with ASP.NET Web API and Swagger UI, but I didn't find any manual describing how to make ASP.NET Core Web API work with MiniProfiler to show results in Swagger UI.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

All you need is to customize Swagger `index.html` file just like it's explained in the [documentation](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/blob/master/README.md#customize-indexhtml). After you created a custom HTML file add the following line into it:

```html
<script async="async" id="mini-profiler" src="/profiler/includes.js?v=4.0.0.0" data-version="4.0.0.0" data-path="/profiler/" data-current-id="865f1487-f416-4d39-87fe-723e34847577" data-ids="" data-position="left" data-authorized="true" data-max-traces="15" data-toggle-shortcut="Alt+P" data-trivial-milliseconds="2.0" data-ignored-duplicate-execute-types="Open,OpenAsync,Close,CloseAsync"></script>
```

Basically the script above is the output of the `MiniProfiler.Current.RenderIncludes()` method.

Here is below the `ConfigureServices` and the `Configure` methods to see how both Swagger and Miniprofiler are configured

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();
    // Register the Swagger generator, defining one or more Swagger documents
    services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info { Title = "My API", Version = "v1" });
    });

    services.AddMiniProfiler(options => 
        options.RouteBasePath = "/profiler"
    );
}

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseMiniProfiler();
    }

    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI(c => {
        c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API V1");
        c.IndexStream = () => GetType().GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("SOMpSwaggerNetCore.SwaggerIndex.html");
    });
    app.UseMvc();
}
```

Comment: OK, I've already done this but customization HTML is the challenge because I can't specify razor statements there to render MiniProfiler view.

Comment: You don't need to. I have added the exact script which shall be added into the HTML file. The solution is not ideal because if you later update the version of the MiniProfiler the output of `RenderIncludes()` method might change and this solution will stop working.

Comment: If you want to render MiniProfiler includes on the fly you can add a bit more JS code to this HTML file which basically makes an AJAX request to your API which returns the result of `MiniProfiler.Current.RenderIncludes` method

Comment: If you didn't set the `RouteBasePath` property in MiniProfiler's options as it's shown above then use default path `/mini-profiler-resources/includes.js`

Comment: I sometimes get 404 for `/mini-profiler-resources/results` so I don't get profiler results for query (it happens occasionally, no pattern detected) but after trying the same it's OK. Is it MiniProfiler bug?

Comment: I guess so, the MiniProfiler for ASP.NET Core is the pre-release package. I would report the issue on their GitHub.